# new to android: need to line buttons up horizontally

Tags: android

I need to line buttons up horizontally, however, my buttons are appearing vertically. They are all stacked up on top of each other.. do you know how I can do this horizontally?

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="88dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


       <Button android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button android:layout_weight="1" />

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Linear layout you can easily represent your button in horizontally.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:orientation="horizontal" >


       <Button android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: When you use the linear layout, be sure to set the orientation to horizontal again.

Comment: but that will affect my views code on the screen, so i cant make this linear layout.

Comment: i tried to make it linearlayout like mohammad suggested, all my buttons dissappeared

Answer (score 0):

You have not identified a [TableRow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html) for your [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html). Imagine how a table is created, row's go horizontally and columns go vertically.

Fixing your code would look something like this

```
<TableLayout
android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="88dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

    <TableRow     
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button android:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Alternatively, to make things easier, I would recommend using a [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) with the orientation set to horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

Use a linearlayout as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#646464"
    android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/inner_artist_profile"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:text="Profile"
        android:textColor="#AEAEAE"
        android:background="@drawable/sub_nav_left" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/inner_artist_news"
       android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
       android:text="News"
       android:textColor="#AEAEAE"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/inner_artist_profile"
       android:background="@drawable/sub_nav_middle" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/inner_artist_events"
 android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:text="Events"
    android:textColor="#AEAEAE"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/inner_artist_news"
    android:background="@drawable/sub_nav_middle" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/inner_artist_videos"
   android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/inner_artist_events"
    android:background="@drawable/sub_nav_middle"
    android:text="Videos"
    android:textColor="#AEAEAE" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/inner_artist_albums"
   android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/inner_artist_videos"
    android:background="@drawable/sub_nav_right"
    android:text="Albums"
    android:textColor="#AEAEAE" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is from a working project modify id's according to need

Answer (score 0):

Or encapsulate the `Button` objects within a `TableRow` tag e.g

```
<TableRow>
    <Button></Button>
</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a TableLayout, I think you should use a LinearLayout with a WeightSum. To distribute the widths of the 4 buttons evenly, set their widths to 0 and their weight to 1. Then set the weight sum of the LinearLayout to 4 (the number of buttons). Like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="88dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:weightSum="4">

    <Button 
       android:layout_width="0dip"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button 
       android:layout_width="0dip"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button 
       android:layout_width="0dip"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button 
       android:layout_width="0dip"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You actually do not need the weightSum property of the LinearLayout, but the weight properties of the buttons are needed.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.Please check following is one of the way

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="4" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add TableRow to TableLayout and here is the working code

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="88dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <Button android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button android:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```